# Unable to create paypal sandbox account outside US

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

How can i create Paypal sandbox account if i live outside US?When i try to sign up it does not give any option to select country, just state option. I have to integrate the Paypal API and have to test it in sandbox.

Comment: May i know the sandbox account country are you looking to create, so that i could share the sandbox signup url. You can choose the account type and sign up. Recommended to follow the steps from the following link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/

Answer (score 8):

Please follow the below steps to create Sandbox account.

1. Login to developer.paypal.com with your LIVE PayPal account
2. Click Dashboard
3. Click sandbox accounts
4. Click Create account button on the top right corner
5. Create a business account for seller and a personal account for buyer
6. Please add bank account and credit card and also populate some amount to your account
7. The email address need not be an real one.

Refer this link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/

Comment: That helped thanks!, this answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Murugesh is accurate but I thought I'd add something.

When creating a sandbox account that way, you can choose from a rather limited list of countries. If your desired country, say Estonia, is in the list, you are in luck. Creating an account that way will automatically setup a rather well-configured account.

However, if you'd like to create an account for a different country, which is not in the list, say Nigeria, you can still do it. According to this post https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Sandbox-Environment/my-country-nigeria-not-listed-in-sandbox-account/m-p/1621520/highlight/true#M2889, here is what you need to do:

1. Go to https://sandbox.paypal.com.
2. Click the flag at the bottom right of the page and then select whatever country from the country list.
3. Sign up for an account inside the sandbox, rather than via the developer dashboard.
4. Go to Developer Dashboard > Accounts. There should be a paragraph "To link other accounts created in sandbox to your developer account, authenticate with the credentials of the test account you want to link" or something similar. Click the link to link the sandbox account you just created to your developer account.

Comment: thanks bro, this is so pathetic from paypal that i have to read random stuff about nigeria on some forum to create test acc for a specific country, instead of just them providing a stupid select options.